# How do a write Test Junit test for messaging with sink and @StreamListener

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring-cloud-stream application with kafka binding. I would like to create a Test Junit.

I have my class definitions such as below:-

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@Slf4j
public class Messaging {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${messaging}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${messaging.prefix}")
    private String messaging;
    
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT) 
    public void handle(Message<String> request) {
        log.info("Topic name ==> %s :", request.getPayload());
        try {   
            String jsonString = request.getPayload().replace("\\", "").replace("\"{", "{").replace("}\"", "}");
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(request.getPayload());
            String urlRequest =url.concat(jsonObject.get("targetClass").getAsString()).concat(messaging);
            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(jsonString, getHeaderMap(request.getHeaders()));
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(urlRequest, entity, String.class);

        
        } catch (ValidationException validationException) {
            log.error("Error de validación: {}", validationException.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have my channel definitions such as below:-

```
public interface Sink {
    String INPUT = "input";

    @Input(Sink.INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

And this my application properties to bind your channels to the same queue:

```
spring:
  cloud: 
    bus: 
      destination:CONFIG
      enabled: true
    stream: 
      bindings:
        input:
          group: input_messaging          
          contentType: application/json
          destination: CONFIG_Test1,CONFIG_Test2
```

This is the test that I have created but it give this erros :
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MessagingTestConfig.class)
public class MessagingListenerTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }
    
    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testReturn() throws Exception {
            
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MessagingTest.class,
                "--server.port=0",
                "--spring.jmx.enabled=false",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=text/plain",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=text/plain");
        
        MessageCollector collector = context.getBean(MessageCollector.class);
        Processor processor = context.getBean(Processor.class);
        Sink inputChannel = context.getBean(Sink.class);
        
        Message<String> request = MessageBuilder.withPayload("headers").setHeader("topicName", "topic-1").build();
        
        inputChannel.input()
                .send(request);
        Message<String> message = (Message<String>) collector
                .forChannel(processor.output()).poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        assertThat(message).isNotNull();
        assertThat(message.getPayload()).contains("topicName");
        context.close();
    }
    
    @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class TestProcessor  {
        
        @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
        public Message<String> hundle(Message<String> messageHundle) {
            return  messageHundle;
        }
    }

    }
```

I wonder if there is and a way to test my class, how to do it and thanks for your help

This is the change using the latest version of Spring Cloud Stream

```
package com.common.messaging;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinderConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:/msc-test.properties")
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MessagingListenerTestConfig.class)
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@DirtiesContext
public class MessagingListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessagingListener listener;

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination inputDestination;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(listener, "restTemplate", restTemplate);

        ResponseEntity<String> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<>("{}", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);

    }

    @Test
    public void testHundleMessage() {

        String expectedUrl = URL;
        Message<String> request = MessageBuilder.withPayload("headers").setHeader("topicName", "topic-1").build();
        log.info("request Test :", request.getPayload());
         
        //inputDestination.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>(request.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        listener.handle(request);

        //Verificar la recepción de los mensajes
        assertThat(outputDestination.receive()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(outputDestination.receive().getPayload().toString()).contains("topicName");

        //Verificar la url del restTemplate
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).postForEntity(expectedUrl, any(), eq(String.class));

    }
}
```

but given this error, and I do not know why

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination.receive(OutputDestination.java:59)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination.receive(OutputDestination.java:73)
at com.common.messaging.MessagingListenerTest.testHundleMessage(MessagingListenerTest.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

Comment: If you are on the latest Spring Cloud Stream, try migrating to the functional model and the new testing strategies: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing

Comment: I have changed the implementation and using InputDestination but I get this error  java.lang.NullPointerException in  inputDestination.send(inputMessage, "myInput");

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample application?

Comment: I have put an example of the class modified to the new spring clous stream

Comment: Thanks for this thread.  I couldn't find this kind of info anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I still having the same problems

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:/msc-test.properties")
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MessagingListenerTestConfig.class)
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@DirtiesContext
public class MessagingListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessagingListener listener;

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination inputDestination;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String EXPECTED_URL = "http://localhost:11000/test/v2/verification/messaging";

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(listener, "restTemplate", restTemplate);

        ResponseEntity<String> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<>("{}", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);

    }

    @Test
    public void testHundleMessage() {

        
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject()
                .put("id", 1)
                .put("targetClass", "/test/v2/verification");
        
        
        Message<String> request = MessageBuilder.withPayload(obj1.toString()).build();
        log.info("request Test : "+ request.getPayload());
         
        
        inputDestination.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>(request.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        listener.handle(request);

        //Verificar la url del restTemplate
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).postForEntity(eq(EXPECTED_URL), any(), eq(String.class));
        
        //Verificar la recepción de los mensajes
        assertThat(outputDestination.receive()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(outputDestination.receive().getPayload().toString()).contains("topicName");


    }

}
```

**just in this line**

```
inputDestination.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>(request.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

**and this the error Junit**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.AbstractDestination.getChannel(AbstractDestination.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination.send(InputDestination.java:37)
    at com.common.messaging.MessagingListenerTest.testHundleMessage(MessagingListenerTest.java:93)
```

**and the console error**

```
2020-07-14 11:29:16.850  INFO 25240 --- [           main] c.b.a.m.c.m.MessagingListenerTest        : The following profiles are active: test
2020-07-14 11:29:18.171  INFO 25240 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2020-07-14 11:29:18.192  INFO 25240 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2020-07-14 11:29:18.212  INFO 25240 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2020-07-14 11:29:18.392  INFO 25240 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-07-14 11:29:18.429  INFO 25240 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-07-14 11:29:20.113  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-07-14 11:29:20.356  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-07-14 11:29:20.358  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel          : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-07-14 11:29:20.361  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-07-14 11:29:20.382  INFO 25240 --- [           main] c.b.a.m.c.m.MessagingListenerTest        : Started MessagingListenerTest in 4.629 seconds (JVM running for 9.331)
2020-07-14 11:29:23.255  INFO 25240 --- [           main] c.b.a.m.c.m.MessagingListenerTest        : request Test : {"targetClass":"/test/v2/verification","id":1}
2020-07-14 11:29:28.207  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-07-14 11:29:28.207  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel          : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-07-14 11:29:28.207  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-07-14 11:29:28.208  INFO 25240 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentpath:"C:\windows\system32\Aternity\Java\JavaHookLoader.dll"="C:\ProgramData\Aternity\hooks"
```

**what could be the problem**

Comment: did you found a solution for this? same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling `outputDestination.receive()` two times. First time you are getting the message and when trying to reach it second time it's not there.
For me was working this approach:

```
String messagePayload = new String(outputDestination.receive().getPayload());
assertThat(messagePayload).contains("topicName");
```